# ImageMagick convert composite many crops from the same image?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a fairly complicated crop-rotate-splice command, here simplified just to crop:

```
magick "$INPUT" -crop "$WIDTH"x"$HEIGHT" "$DESTINATION"
```

I would like to cut out many parts of the same `$INPUT` image, and then finally lay them all on top of each other using `convert -composite`.

How can I do this without using temporary files?

I think I should be able to

```
convert \( "$INPUT" -crop ... \) \( "$INPUT" -crop ... \) \( "$INPUT" -crop ... \) \( "$INPUT" -crop ... \) -composite "$DESTINATION"
```

But is there a way that can also avoid having to repeat the input image path for every cropping?

Comment: You cannot composite more than 2 images at a time using convert ... -composite.  If you want to do that, then you need to use convert ... -flatten assuming they are all offset at the same location. If you need to offset them differently, then use -set page in each parentheses after the crop. Don't forget to add +repage right after the crop.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for pointing that out. `-flatten` doesn't work at all for me, would you mind taking a look at my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78177689/3310334

Comment: See GeeMack's solution. You did not put +repage after your crops as I said above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a particular image several times in an ImageMagick command, you can read it into the command once, store it in an IM memory register "mpr:something" during the command, and recall it when you need it.

```
magick "$input" -write mpr:img1 +delete \( mpr:img1 ... \) \( mpr:img1 ... \) ...
```

Name it "mpr:anyname". You can write to and read from as many of these memory stored images as you want. They exist until the end of the command.

Comment: What's `+delete` for here?

Comment: I used "+delete" to remove the immediately previous image, the input image here, from the active command after reading it in. Then every time we need that image we read it back into the command from the memory register "mpr:img1".

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing this rather than the OP way?

Comment: Probably depends on your work flow. I find it easy to keep track of that input image if I store it as "mpr:myimage", delete it from the active command with "+delete", and only use it from there onward by recalling "mpr:myimage".