# How to composite more than 2 images with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How can I overlap several images on top of each other using imagemagick?

I have a base image `layers.png`:

[image]

I want to cut out different parts of the image and overlap them. E.g., overlap the skeletal rib cage and blood vessels of the left arm on top of the muscle body (desired output):

[image]

So I have extracted the different parts I need:

```
% convert layers.png -crop 400x1048+0+0 body.png
% convert layers.png -crop 140x180+522+230 -alpha set -channel Alpha -evaluate multiply 0.8 +channel -background none -gravity north -splice x230 -gravity west -splice 122x +gravity ribs.png
% convert layers.png -crop 100x340+1434+245 -alpha set -channel Alpha -evaluate multiply 0.8 +channel -background none -gravity north -splice x245 -gravity west -splice 271x +gravity arm.png
```

Using `-splice` to offset the body parts according to how they will be offsetted from the top-left corner in the composited image.

Compositing these images works for two at a time:

```
% convert body.png ribs.png -composite body_and_ribs.png
```

[image]

But it does not work for three at a time:

```
% convert body.png ribs.png arm.png -composite all.png
```

[image]

And my other attempt with `-flatten` instead of `-composite` is even further from what I want:

```
% convert body.png ribs.png arm.png -flatten all.png
```

[image]

How can I simply overlap more than two input images on top of each other in imagemagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the flattened pieces to align properly, the ImageMagick solution is to "+repage" them so they all start with the same geometry before the "-flatten".

I've put your entire operation into a single command, reading the input  once and using it to make all three parts, then flatten and write the output.

```
magick convert layers.png -background none -write mpr:img0 +delete ^
   ( mpr:img0 -crop 400x1048+0+0 ) ^
   ( mpr:img0 -crop 140x180+522+230 ^
      -channel A -evaluate multiply 0.8 +channel -splice 122x230 ) ^
   ( mpr:img0 -crop 100x340+1434+245 ^
      -channel A -evaluate multiply 0.8 +channel -splice 271x245 ) ^
   +repage -flatten body_and_ribs.png
```

That command is in Windows CLI syntax, and produces the image below.

The command uses IM's built-in memory register "mpr:anyname" to hold the input image for re-use several times. Inside each set of parentheses the input image gets cropped as necessary, the alpha adjusted, and spliced to locate it in the result. After the parentheses all three images get a "+repage" so they all line up properly with the "-flatten".

[image]

Comment: You're my ImageMagick guru! Thanks for another great answer. It's a bit surprising to me that `+repage` only needs to be used once, instead of after each input that would have its own geometry.

Comment: Do you know how to flatten images aligned by their centers, instead of by their top left corners?

Comment: I've asked a question about how to flatten images aligning by their centers, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78179851/3310334